# tensorflow TFRecord k-hot encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am trying to create my training dataset with the TFRecord format following this tutorial : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md for API detection.

But, instead of using one hot encoding, I would like to use k-hot encoding. For example instead of having [0 0 0 1 0] labels, I can have [0 1 0 1 0] so multi-classification. I was wondering how to do that with the TFRecord format. Do I have to create two `tf.train.example` if I use 2-hot encoding ? (using two times the same bouding box coordinates) or is there another way ? (like using for example `'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text)`, and `'image/object/class/text2': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text2))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a list of labels like [0, 1, 2] and 10 classes, you need to

```
def int64_feature(value):
    if type(value) != list:
        value = [value]
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
```

Then you pass label to tf.Example as one of the features

```
'label': int64_feature(label)
```

After that, when you parse your dataset during training, you decole label like this:

```
tf.reduce_max(tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes, dtype=tf.int32), axis=0)
```

Which gives

```
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```